# firebase how many current logged in user in my app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So i have app with Firebase email Auth

I want to keep track of how many users are actively logged in right now

A number in firebase database that can keep changing or list of active users right now!

They are removed moment user logs out

We cant exactly do addition in firebase database so how to do that.. any help?

PS: I dont want to use Analytics, i want a database solution

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database documentation has an [example of such a presence system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-sample), which seems what you're looking for. Covering it in an answer is a bit broad for Stack Overflow. But if you get stuck implementing it, post back with the [minimal complete that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use firebase StreamView : RealTime Analytics

Below are the details

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7229836?hl=en

http://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/realtime-analytics-for-everyone.html

Comment: Nah! I dont want to use analytics... no i want counter in firebase databse

Comment: That will bloat your app

Comment: exactly - i dont want any code inside app.. on the firebase database

Answer (score 0):

For real hardcore database solution you can do the following:

You can add a `last_login` field in your database users collection. Update that field whenever a user resumes your app. Then you will be able to query once or Live Stream about how many users are logged in the last several minutes.

If you are looking for something much more accurate you can update the user `last_login` every several seconds from your application and Live Stream the last results.

Note that this may cost you a lot of money since firestore is a pay per action database, Which means that you pay for each update and each read from your database.

You can also checkout @Frank van Puffelen comment bellow your answer.

Enjoy!